# retrieve functor name knowing its parameters

Tags: prolog

How I can retrieve a functor name knowing its parameters , my functor are dynamic and not static .
 I tried this code `Fun=..[Functor,1,2],call(Fun).`
But I got error of not sufficient instanciation .Is there another possible way to have it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't identify a *predicate* (they're not called *functions*) just by its parameters since that's ambiguous. `Fun =.. [Functor, 1, 2]` will only work if `Functor` or `Fun` is instantiated.

Comment: There are some ways of achieving things like this, but it depends on your use case. What is your use case?

Comment: Always write `call(Functor,1,2)` in place of `Fun=..[Functor,1,2],call(Fun).`

Comment: @aBathologist  my use case is I generate some prolog facts and I want to build xml file out of them , the root and other elements of I know them from IDs ,element(id , parentid) , attribute(parentid, value). so I want to access to each element and each chiledren and attributs ,the generated prolog facts for sure are dynamic .

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not a practical solution, since there is 
[current_predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=examineprog)(:PredicateIndicator) that can enumerate all known predicates (not *functions*) of given arity (2 in your case). But then you will get all autoloaded predicates, etc...

Try

```
?- current_predicate(X/2).
```

Once you get a candidate, you can call clause/2, to inspect if the candidate matches your needs...